# Travel history for the last 7 years

Tags: i-94

I came to the USA last in 2011. Never left the country after that. Now I cannot find my I-94 online. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: You never left which country? The USA or some other country? How long were you in the US for? What do you think the lack of an online I-94 might be a problem for? I'm really not sure what problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: how did you stay in the US for seven years with an I-94? that might be your bigger problem, if you have no visa or green card.

Answer (score 1):

Electronic I-94s only started in mid-2013 for people arriving by air. All I-94s issued before that were paper I-94s. If you arrived as a nonimmigrant in 2011, you should have filled out an I-94 when you arrived and received the small rectangular stub back, and it would usually be tucked or stapled into your passport (with the possible exception of Canadian citizens arriving by land, who sometimes don't get I-94s, or Mexicans arriving with Border Crossing Cards). Did you lose it?